# Ordering entities based on other entity content

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

My problem is that I don't know how to write this query.

I have a entity Conversation

```
   public class Conversation : Entity
    {
        protected Conversation() { }

        [Required]
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; protected set; }

        public virtual HashSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

and an entity message

```
public class Message : Entity<long>
    {
        protected Message()
        { }

        public DateTime CreationDate { get; protected set; }

        [Required]
        public string Msg { get; protected set; }
}
```

I want to retrieve the conversations ordered by the most recent message written on it.

By most recent I mean the most closely written on the conversation.

Somebody can help me here?

Comment: Why are you using a `HashSet` (especially since `Message` doesn't override `Equals` or `GetHashCode` that you've shown)?

Comment: I override it on the generic implementation of the entity. But that is not my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look at the max message creation data for each conversation:

```
var query = conversations.OrderByDescending(c => c.Messages.Max(m => n.CreationDate))
```